# create table daily to store the log reports in Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Our project, we are tracking the log reports for each day, now we are writing data to a files which has all the records

we are now storing the data to database,

My Question is we are planned to create table daily to store the log reports. Is this a correct Process

Answer (score 4):

Create a single table to store your log entries.  Modern databases can handle millions (or even billions) of rows in a single table without any issue.

This will allow you to do analysis on any of your log entries using a single set of queries.  You won't have to write different queries (or use dynamic SQL) to read from each different days' entries.

Comment: But having seperate tables seems to be a better design, especially when the older logs become less useful and so it would degrade the performance to have it in the same table. In that case, is there any easy way to schedule the creation of new tables in a periodic manner??

Comment: If you use separate tables, you cannot do easy queries that traverse day boundaries (in a specific timezone).  It depends on your needs, but I would steer away from it unless absolutely essential.